# How do you add 25% to any value or variable in decimal format

Tags: c#, percentage

My code is here

```
    if (dUIAnswer == "yes" || dUIAnswer == "ya")
    {
        quote += (25 / 100) * quote;            
    }

    if (coverageType == "full coverage")
        quote += (50 / 100) * quote; ;


   return quote;
```

I am basically trying to increase the value "quote" by 25% of itself if the user has a DUI. Please give me a simple solution of code that is possible.

Comment: What is the type of `quote`?

Comment: What's not working about this code?

Comment: A decimal type, it is a variable of type decimal.

Comment: @JeffreyPadgett The problem in your code is that you actually do an integer division, so `(25 / 100)` results to 0, and the whole sentence on the right side results to 0. Just do `quote *= 1.25`.

Comment: The value remains the same for some reason. Maybe the IF statement is not detecting the string value of DUI answer? I’m not sure. I’ll double check in debug mode.

Comment: `quote += (25M / 100M) * quote;`

Comment: Thank you so much, absolutely correct. I appreciate it so much.

Comment: @JeffreyPadgett when you were asked what is not working about the code, they didn't mean what is the cause of it not working. They meant what is the behavior you observe that doesn't match to the expected behavior. A good, clear question should be alone the lines: "I tried this. I expect this, but instead this happens" You haven't mention in your question what is the problem with the code i.e. what is it's behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much @bolov .. This was one of my very first StackOverflow questions and I will do better next time.

Comment: Also worth noting is that _quote += quote * 25 / 100;_ would also work, with the first value in the expression being a decimal the compiler will do it's best to convert other values to appropriate types - with the brackets there the integer value would be calculated before type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

`25 / 100` does integer division so the result is `0` (of type `int`). Make them decimal i.e. `25.0M / 100.0M` or better yet:

```
quote *= 1.25M;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add 25% to the cyrrent value so it will become 125% of the current value, so multipy it by 1.25 (125%):

```
if (dUIAnswer == "yes" || dUIAnswer == "ya")
        quote *= 1.25M;         

    if (coverageType == "full coverage")
        quote *= 1.5M;
```

Comment: "quote" is a decimal variable, so needs multiplying by 1.25M & 1.5M otherwise you get a compile time error (_CS0019 Operator '*=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'_)

Comment: @pau you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: the result of `25 / 100` or `50 / 100` is `0`, in C# and similar languages (C, C++, ...).

Why?

In C#, when you divide an integer (`int`, `long`, etc.) by an integer, the decimal section is truncated - `0.25` becomes `0`.

So, there are some solutions:

1) Simply write `0.25` (or `0.5`) in your code:

```
if (dUIAnswer == "yes" || dUIAnswer == "ya")
{
    quote += 0.25 * quote;            
}

if (coverageType == "full coverage")
    quote += 0.5 * quote; ;


return quote;
```

2) Convert one of the numebrs to `double` or to `float`, by attaching it the postfix `D` (for `double`) or `F` (for `float`), or by adding to it an `.0` at the end (which does it a `double`), or by casting it with `(<type>)`:

```
if (dUIAnswer == "yes" || dUIAnswer == "ya")
{
    quote += (25.0 / 100D) * quote;            
}

if (coverageType == "full coverage")
    quote += ((float)50 / 100) * quote; ;


return quote;
```

(You also can convert it to `decimal`, explicitly or by attaching `M` as postfix).

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help very much. This is a perfect explanation.